# What are these incompatible micro usb type B plugs?

Tags: usb

I have 2 usb cables, both of them appear to be micro usb type B. Both of them are almost the same but the second one has 5 tracks on top (see 2nd image), while the 1st one has not them (1st image). The 1st one is newer than the 2nd. The problem is that the 2nd does not fit well to Android smartphone, I recently bought. It seems I can charge it but can't do data transfer. I thought that all micro usb type B plugs are compatible and interchangeable. So does micro usb type B plugs subdivide on several more types and what are these types?

[image: the first one]

[image: the second one]

Comment: Is there connectivity between the shields at each end?

Comment: I can use 2nd cable on my old Android smartphone and both charging and data transfer works. And I can use 1st cable on my new Android smartphone (charging and data transfer works). But I can't data transfer on new smartphone with 2nd cable (because of incompatibility?).

Comment: You said that you have 2 cables, and you described them, but added stock photos?! How can we give an good answer about the two cables differences with just stock photos? Maybe one of your cables is deffective.

Comment: There are cheapskate charge-only cables in the market which have only 2 wires. That's common knowledge, or at least it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice that for the first time but it turned out that significant difference between the 2 cables was the height of plugs. The height differs in about several millimeters and that's why one of the plugs didn't fit well (the shorter one). So answering my own question:

> does micro usb type B plugs subdivide on several more types

No, but physical dimensions of the plug may vary and that can make them not interchangeable between devices. Here is the photo of the plugs:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those photos aren't from your plugs. Both are in the web. The second one is in Wikipedia. You said that have 2 cables, and you described them, but added stock photos?!

**MICRO** USB male plug **always** have space for 5 pins. Pin 1 for +5v, pin 2 is Data-, pin 3 is Data+, and 5 is for GND.

Pin 4 is used in "Host cables", or "OTG Cables" (OTG stands for "on the go"), the OTG cable is used, e.g., to connect a USB drive to a cell phone. The device must support the OTG option. Pin 4 is shunted to ground, sometimes with a resistor.

In most of USB cables the fourth pin is present, but unconnected. Some cables don't have the fourth pin, but there is a gap where it should be its place.

**MINI** USB has a different plug, also with 5 pins, see the image below.

[image]